# $f(z)=\frac{\sin \sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{z}}-c $ has a solution for every $c\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\frac{\sin \sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{z}}-c $. Show that $f(z)$ has solution for every $c\in \mathbb{C}$

I was trying to prove this by contradiction using  the order of $f(z)$ which is $\frac{1}{2}$

Suppose there exist a $c \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)-c\neq 0$ for every $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

Or $f(z)\neq c$ , that is $|f(z)|<|c|$ or $|f(z)|>c$

Can I contradict the order of $f(z)$ is not $1/2 $ from here?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** What do you know about an entire function that is never $0$? See if that's possible with a non-integral order.

Comment: The reciprocal is bounded and entire. But not sure if you pointing to these properties.

Comment: The reciprocal is bounded? No. But, no, think about the fact that $\Bbb C$ is simply connected.

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to indicate.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific?

Comment: Every nowhere-zero analytic function on a simply connected domain has a logarithm.